# Do Persian Adjectives have Masc. Fem. and Neuter forms

Tags: adjectives, gender, persian

For adjectives in Farsi (Persian), do they have Masculine, Feminine, and Neuter.

For Example:

The adjective خوب (Khoob, meaning good), does it have different forms, like in French or Russian?

Thank you, all help is appreciated :D!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Farsi has no grammatical gender, its nouns are not divided into Masculine, Feminine, and Neuter, neither are its adjectives. Farsi even has no distinction between 'he' and 'she', both of them are the same, /u/ او.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Yellow Sky, however I just need to add that some adjectives which are borrowed from Arabic have actually brought the Feminine and Masculine forms which happen to be actually used a lot in legal/formal context.

An example would be:

محترم and محترمه
(meaning respectful, honourable, respected)

Which is a title referred to a man and woman.